# php login which select username from multiple table

Tags: php, sql, algorithm, authentication

as tittle given, i try to learn the basic login php but got got stuck on sql which i need query to produce username and password from multiple table like customer,admin,storeowner,dispatch.

```
customer
+---------+----------+---------+
| cust_id | username | password |
+---------+----------+---------+
|  1      | cust1    | pass1   |
|  2      | cust2    | pass2   |
+---------+----------+---------+

admin
+----------+----------+---------+
| admin_id | username | password |
+----------+----------+---------+
|  1       | admin1   | pass1   |
|  2       | admin2   | pass2   |
+----------+----------+---------+

storeowner
+-------------+----------+---------+
| storeown_id | username | password |
+-------------+----------+---------+
|  1          | st1      | pass1   |
|  2          | st2      | pass2   |
+-------------+----------+---------+

dispatch
+-------------+----------+---------+
| dispatch_id | username | password |
+-------------+----------+---------+
|  1          | dist1    | pass1   |
|  2          | dist2    | pass2   |
+-------------+----------+---------+
```

---

php code

```
if($submit_value == 'login' ){
        $username = $_POST['username'];
        $password = $_POST['password'];
            $sql = "SELECT * FROM customer WHERE username = '$username' AND password = '$password'";
            $query = mysqli_query($dbconn,$sql) or die("Error: " . mysql_error());
            $row = mysqli_num_rows($query);
            $r = mysqli_fetch_assoc($query);
            if($row == 0 ) {
                $msg = "<div class='alert alert-danger'>
                <span class='login_content'></span> &nbsp; Invalid Username or Password !
                </div>";
            }
            else {
                $msg = "<div class='alert alert-danger'>
                <span class='login_content'></span> &nbsp; valid !
                </div>";
                $_SESSION['id'] = $r['id'];
                $_SESSION['level'] = '2';
                header('Location: /testing/user/index.php');
            }
    }
```

this is sample of after form post, and the way i understand, after i got the correct sql query, i will need to extend the else condition something like this :

```
else {
  .....
  if($id == 'customer'){
     $_SESSION['id'] = $r['id'];
     $_SESSION['level'] = '2';
     header('Location: /testing/customer/index.php');
  }
  if($id == 'admin'){
     $_SESSION['id'] = $r['id'];
     $_SESSION['level'] = '2';
     header('Location: /testing/admin/index.php');
  }
}
```

---

is this how others people make their php? or there is another way without sql query select username & password multiple table to create an session and navigate to other location.

as i said, i still on learning, i dont know any other way of login or how **normally people approach for php login**, therefor i highly thankfull for any idea or information that can help me to more understanding on php login other necessary thing that i need to understand on php. 
Sorry for my english. Thanks.

Comment: ok - you have a basic mistake which makes your code vulnerable to SQL injection. The user's password also appears to be stored in plaintext rather than hashed using `password_hash`...

Comment: Jolly good @MikeAbineri - for it wasn't me that downvoted!

Comment: haha yeah I figured it wouldnt be, just shocks me how unforgiving some people are on stack,  I know quality needs to be maintained and im all for that but more often than not when people dont UNDERSTAND the answers provided in questions already submitted)  and ask the same question but with more clarification if often results in "ALREADY BEEN ASKED" and downvotes :P tad harsh considering people are just trying to learn.

Comment: @Syn is right on this one, programming isnt really one of those learn as you do things as it can have bad consequences security wise. Personally I recommend Udemy, when the courses are on offer they are only 10 quid each (or dollars w/e) and pick up an object orientated php course, and one for mysql as well, I used the most popular course by edwin diaze, It can be really boring and youll be tempted to skip it but dont, every single bit of knowledge you gain makes you a better dev!

Comment: "pasword" and "password"; which one is it?

Comment: `mysql_error()` doesn't work with the mysqli_ api.

Answer (score 2):

So when submitting a login and making sure the login matches a couple of suggestions:

In your database you want your password to be stored safely in the database (I recommend using password_hash) so create a password column VARCHAR 255 and in it, you want to store and encrypted password

And example of this is:

```
echo password_hash('passwordhere',PASSWORD_DEFAULT);
```

That will echo what the password is in its encrypted form, for testing purposes store that encrypted string in your database along with your username FYI based on the example above the string would look like this

```
$2y$10$plno2UTlMbRNghYKz6MgQeXoyJihTvuq6aq6oW2rO9wwHM6BUzNL.
```

So Store your DB columns would look like this

```
Username: Admin
Password: $2y$10$plno2UTlMbRNghYKz6MgQeXoyJihTvuq6aq6oW2rO9wwHM6BUzNL.
```

Now when trying to login you want to make a function that checks the username and decrypts the password to do this you need to get the stored password encryption string then decrypt it using a function called password_verify, so below is an example of what I would use to return a correct login assuming your table is called login)

I'm going to assume you know how to get MySQL results and won't go into that.

```
public function($username,$password){
//$username is the username the user submitted via the form
//$password is the password the user submitted via the form
 $sql = "SELECT password FROM logins WHERE username = '$username'";
 $result = mysqli_query($dbconnection, $sql);
 if ($result->num_rows >= 1) { 
    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
          $returned_password_hash = $row; // This will return the password hash that matches the username the user inputted
    if (password_verify($password, $returned_password_hash)) {
         $logged_in = 1
         return $logged_in'
    }   
}
```

Please note that is a DEMO function that would return TRUE if the submitted password matches the submitted username; do not copy and paste that as none of the input is escaped (which is very important for any user submitted input going into your DB) and it's not very tidy. I just wanted to show you the concept which I shall sum up below:

- get the password hash from  database that matches the username supplied (make sure your username column is unique)
- Once you have the password hash use password_very($submitted_password,$the_hash_from_the_database)
- if password_very returns true then the login is correct!

I suggest you read up on these two functions

https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.password-hash.php

https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.password-verify.php

Note that the php manual can be confusing for first timers.

Comment: haha, not worry about downvotes. The reason i create new question because i cant find a way other question is related to mine or can solve mine. Mybe with such little information provide make other hard to help or misunderstanding. Thanks for password hash. Really thanks..